# Spritekit: Pausing parent node does not pause child node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I am creating my first game in SpriteKit. I am trying to pause my GameScene and then run some animations via SpriteKit. The issue was that if I pause the scene using `self.view?.isPaused = true` everything stops. After searching around I found that the way to do this is to add another node to the scene and make everything else that you want to pause, child nodes of that node. I am trying to do that but haven't been successful. This is the code that I have

```
var worldNode:SKNode?
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    worldNode = SKNode()
    self.addChild(self.worldNode!)

    let spriteNode:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red_ball")
    spriteNode.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    spriteNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 15)
    spriteNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    self.worldNode?.addChild(spriteNode)
    spriteNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10))


    self.worldNode?.isPaused = true
    //self.view?.isPaused = true
}
```

when I run this I see the ball moving on the screen which should not happen according to my understanding, since I am pausing the `worldNode` and the `spriteNode` is child node of that. If I use `self.view?.isPaused = true` to pause the scene, then the ball is stationary as expected. Am I missing something ? how can I add nodes to the `worldNode` and then just pause only those nodes by pausing `worldNode`. Thanks !

Comment: after posting this I realized that even pausing the child node directly with spriteNode.isPaused = true, does not pause it, maybe the nodes with impluses applied cannot be paused this way ? Looks like I need to find an alternative, maybe use UI animation instead, which will continue to work even if the scene is paused

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to pause nodes moved by impulses and forces is certainly to pause the scene:

```
self.isPaused = true
```

but I would say that you want to have other nodes unpaused (eg. HUD elements) so you added your game elements into world node.

So one way to pause physics along with pausing the node is to pause the complete physics world, like this:

```
self.physicsWorld.speed = 0
```

Comment: do note that isPaused is bugged, for some reason it flips all of the children isPaused state as well, which is bad. (Let's say you have a paused particle emitter on the scene,  if you set the scene to unpause, the emitter will prematurely fire)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Forgot that little fact and I do remember that were mentions about it, thanks. Personally I don't use it at all to pause the scene, because I like to have world node and to pause it instead.

Comment: even world node is affected by it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Of course, but if you don't pause the scene, then there is no harm. That was my point...

Comment: if you pause world node, and you have an emitter on world node, same results happen lol

Comment: I have no idea why apple recursively changes all the children values, it has no reason to, but they do it anyway